# How to call a customer tensorflow op. in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have a customer Tensorflow op. that wrote in C++ and was build successfully to call in Tensorflow code as

```
from libs.customer_op import customer_op
output = customer_op(x, filter=w, rates=[1, 1, rate, rate], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, stride, stride])
```

Now, I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend. Is it possible to call my above function in Keras. Do we need do some extra register step?

**Update:** Thanks Matias Valdenegro for your suggestion. I have tried it. This is my full code in tensorflow and what I have done in Keras. 
-Tensorflow code

```
def my_conv(input,num_o,kernel_size, stride):
    num_x = input.shape[3].value
    offset = slim.conv2d(input, 18, [kernel_size, kernel_size], stride=stride, activation_fn=None, scope='offset', normalizer_fn=None)
    w = tf.get_variable('weights', shape=[num_o, num_x, kernel_size, kernel_size],
                    initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    output = customer_conv(x, filter=w, offset=offset,padding="SAME")
```

-Keras code:

```
def my_conv(input, num_o, kernel_size, stride):
   num_x = input.shape[3].value
   offset = KL.Conv2D(18, (kernel_size, kernel_size), strides=(stride,stride))(input)
   w = KI.TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None)
   output = Lambda(lambda x: deform_conv_op(x, filter=w, offset=offset, padding="SAME"))(input)
   return output
```

So, this is the place that I will call the function

```
class CustomerCNN():
    def __init__(self, mode):        
        self.mode = mode

    def build(self, mode):

        # Inputs
        input_image = KL.Input(
            shape=config.IMAGE_SHAPE.tolist(), name="input_image")       
        f1 = Lambda(lambda x: my_conv(x, 256, 3, 1))(input_image)
```

For above solution, I still remain the issue:

1. How to initial weight with shape as  `shape=[num_o, num_x, kernel_size, kernel_size]` in Keras
2. How to call my customer conv `my_conv` in the class `CustomerCNN`? Do we need one more Lambda function as I did

Answer (score 2):

You can just call it with a lambda layer:

```
output = Lambda(lambda x: customer_op(x, filter=w, rates=[1, 1, rate, rate],
                padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, stride, stride]))(input)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Matias Valdenegro. I have updated my question based on your comment but still remain some bugs. Could you give me some advice to fix them?